# PHP cannot get the environment variables

Tags: php, bash, operating-system, environment-variables, phpdotenv

I have some environment variables as bash variable and other environment variables into a .env file.
In my php script I load env variable using this

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

but in this way I have only the `.env file variables`, how can I get the **bash environment variables**???

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
// Example use of getenv()
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

from the PHP documentation,
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: `$_ENV` and `getenv ` get the same result of `$dotenv->load()` and the result is the file .env variables, `$_SERVER` get the http request variables. I need the bash environment variables ( or the Operating System environment variables )

Comment: I think your .env file is overwriting the bash variables which are already available. Try to get a bash environment variable without loading your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

As said before by @Shaqil Ismail, try using

```
$variable = $_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME'];
```

I've been days stuck with the problem until now. For the record, I was using `getenv()` and also `$_ENV`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35838422)